# In Jade, how to pass parameters in the onclick function call

Tags: javascript, pug

```
a(id='myLinkTag' onclick='myFunction(' + user._id + ')' href='') Delete
```

Here user._id is the variable and trying to pass that value to myFunction .

syntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that javascript is expecting quotes around functions. What jade is making is `<a id='myLinkTag' onclick='myFunction(userid) href=''>`

This is not what javascript is expecting, Javascript expects a valid variable name to be given to its onclick functions. There are two choices:

- If you are **SURE** that there is **NO WAY** for user._id to ever be anything other than a string **ONLY CONTAINING** alphanumeric characters (`new RegExp(/^(A-Za-z0-9)+$/)`) then put quotes in myFunction: `a(id='myLinkTag' onclick='myFunction(\'' + user._id + '\')' href='') Delete`
- If user._id can be more than alphanumeric characters, you can instead use jade to set a class and a custom attribute like `a(id='myLinkTag' class="myclass" userid=user._id href='') Delete` then in javascript you can:

:

```js
$(".myclass").click(function(e){
    var userid = $(e.target).attr("userid");
    console.log(userid);
    alert(userid);
});
```

```css
Jade would be:

a(id='myLinkTag' class="myclass" userid=user._id href='#')
a(id='myLinkTag2' class="myclass" userid=user2._id href='#')
a(id='myLinkTag3' class="myclass" userid=user3._id href='#')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="myclass" userid="myuserid" href="#">link</a>
<a class="myclass" userid="myuserid2" href="#">link2</a>
<a class="myclass" userid="myuserid3" href="#">link3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use differing nested quotation marks so that you pass a string to your function.

```
a(id='myLinkTag' onclick="myFunction(' + user._id + ')" href='') Delete
```

Comment: if I read the question right, that's not going to work because user._id is a jade variable not a js one

Comment: i could print  in a table as " td #{user._id} " . now i am trying to send that value in the onclick event. Differing nested quotation is not working, in that case "user._id" is considered as string and that is sent.

Comment: @Bhavana I've given an example of passing the id in as an attribute to use in an onclick function in my answer